# Simple proxy server for Windows that supports chaining proxies?

Tags: windows, proxy, transparent-proxy

Are there any small/simple proxy servers for Windows, that support chaining further proxies?

Example:

Browser connects to proxy server.
Proxy server connects to another proxy server.
Proxy server connects yet another proxy server.

Traffic:  Browser --> Proxy --> Proxy #2 --> Proxy #3 --> Website

Answer (score 0):

You must explicit "simple". Microsoft TMG (isa 2006 replacement) can do that, among many others things.

More simple one, and free, [Squid](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/). Famous on Linux/unix, they provide binary for Windows. Never tested myself on Windows